# Remove the form element and in its place put a div with a unique id?

Tags: javascript, html

What does my teacher mean by this exactly? I have very little experience with HTML so I'm not sure what to do? Wouldn't it stop working without the form element?
The whole instructions say:
" Remove the form element and in its place put a div with a unique id.  Don’t forget the closing div element.  Add a second button for Delete Task.  Change the “submit” type to “button” for both buttons and give each one a unique id."

```js
(function(){
    
 // Variable that stores the tasks:
    var tasks = []; 

 // Function called when the form is submitted.
 // Function adds a task to the global array.
    function addTask() {
        'use strict';
        var task = document.getElementById('task');
        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        var message = '';

        if (task.value) {
            tasks.push(task.value);
            message = '<h2>To-Do</h2><ol>';
            for (var i = 0, count = tasks.length; i < count; i++) {
                message += '<li>' + tasks[i] + '</li>';
            }
            message += '</ol>';
            output.innerHTML = message;        
        } // End of task.value IF.

     // Return false to prevent submission:
        return false;

    } // End of addTask() function.

    // Initial setup:
    function init() {
        'use strict';
        document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = addTask;
    } // End of init() function.
    window.onload = init;

})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>To-Do List</title>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Script 6.5 - task.html -->
    <form action="#" method="post" id="theForm">
        <fieldset><legend>Enter an Item To Be Done</legend>
            <div><label for="task">Task</label><input type="text" name="task" id="task" required></div>
            <input type="submit" value="Add It!" id="submit">
      <div id="output"></div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <script src="js/todo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Share the code of _js/todo.js_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need change your event from onsubmit to on click since form is not available anymore.

Try this :

```js
(function(){
    
 // Variable that stores the tasks:
    var tasks = []; 

 // Function called when the form is submitted.
 // Function adds a task to the global array.
    function addTask() {
        'use strict';
        var task = document.getElementById('task');
        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        var message = '';

        if (task.value) {
            tasks.push(task.value);
            message = '<h2>To-Do</h2><ol>';
            for (var i = 0, count = tasks.length; i < count; i++) {
                message += '<li>' + tasks[i] + '</li>';
            }
            message += '</ol>';
            output.innerHTML = message;        
        } // End of task.value IF.

     // Return false to prevent submission:
        return false;

    } // End of addTask() function.

    // Initial setup:
    function init() {
        'use strict';
        document.getElementById('submit').onclick = addTask;
    } // End of init() function.
    window.onload = init;

})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>To-Do List</title>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Script 6.5 - task.html -->
    <form action="#" method="post" id="theForm"
        <fieldset><legend>Enter an Item To Be Done</legend>
            <div><label for="task">Task</label><input type="text" name="task" id="task" required></div>
            <input type="submit" value="Add It!" id="submit">
      <div id="output"></div>
        </fieldset>
   </form>
    <script src="js/todo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wait, so the changes are just made in the j.s code?

Comment: Yes, onsubmit event is available in form element only so you need to change it with your button's click event.